# Predict the price of single part after running the ML algorithm

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

I am working on a problem to predict the price of a mechanical part. I collected all the necessary data and variables.($1200 \times 25$)

I have build multiple models using $log$ transformations of the response variable and two of the predictors. I have fairly good accuracy: 89%. Testing and validation of the model are done. There is no multicollinearity. $R^2$, F statistics, P value and adjusted $R^2 - $  everything is perfect. I have predicted the values on the test set. (250 parts values). Predictions are spot on.
[image]
Model is -

```
test <- lm (log(price) ~ log(SurfaceArea) + log(Quantity) + density + Complexity + 
            Y + X + PricePerKg, data = Training)
```

Now, I want to know how can I predict the price of just one part from the coefficients from my model. Is there any way to predict the price of just one part on the basis of the results?

I want to predict the price of one part if I have the values for: SurfaceArea, quantity, density, complexity Y, X, [PricePerKg].

I hope my problem is clear now.

Comment: I assume that PricePerKg is given, too, which is why I added it in brackets at the end

Comment: `help("predict.lm")`

Comment: I think, help("predict.lm"), will predict for a whole test set not an individual part.

Comment: You think wrong. You can pass new data to `predict` and it will then only predict for this data.

Comment: Yes, you can use $predict$ with $newdata= [a~data~ frame ~that~ only~ has~ one~ row]$, which is the predictors you mean to predict with. But they you will be getting the log(price) rather than price. Hopefully you won't have any problem converting it to price.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume your model parameters are given by $w_{parname}$, the predicted price of one part $\hat{price}$ is given by

$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{price} &= exp(w_0) \times \frac{SurfaceArea^{w_{SurfaceArea}}}{ Quantity^{|w_{Quantity}|}} \times \\
&\times exp \bigg( w_{density} density + w_{machinability} machinability + \\
& + w_{Complexity} Complexity + w_Y Y + w_z Z + \\
& + w_{PricePerKg} PricePerKg \bigg), \\
& given ~ w_{quality}<0
\end{aligned}
$$

where the data

> SurfaceArea, quantity, density, machinability, complexity Y, Z, [PricePerKg]

are provided.

---

The R solution, as indicated above

> v2_data = data.frame(Price=c(...), Y=c(...), X=c(...), Price_Per_kg=c(...), Surface_area=c(...),  Complexity=c(...), density=c(...), Order_Qty=c(...))
>
> ModelY <- lm(log(Price) ~Y + X + Price_Pr_kg + log(Surface_area) + Complexity + density + log(Order_Qty),data=v2_data)
>
> newdata=data.frame(Price=c(1000), Y=c(12), X=c(-3), Price_Per_kg=c(42), Surface_area=c(3.14),  Complexity=c(8), density=c(1.04), Order_Qty=c(144))
>
> logPrice_preds<-predict.lm(ModelY,newdata,type="terms")
>
> Price_preds <- exp(logPrice_preds)

Comment: Thank you so much sir, Just a clarification. First part of the formula you just told me Is it Price = (SurfaceArea^B1 * Quantity^B2) * exp(B3*density + B4*machinability + B5*Complexity + B6*Y + B7*Z + B8*Price Per density) What about the intercept ? And the coefficient for quantity is negative.

Comment: The intercept $w_0$ turns into $exp(w_0)$ and it multiplies this whole expression. The coefficient for quantity may be negative. There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I am sorry sir, But Price_preds gives => Y = 2.1044,   X = 0.977, PPKG = 0.9856, log(SA) = 3.909, Complexity = 1.58, density= 0.94, log(quantity) = 0.866, attr("constant") = 6.32, when I input values- 609,61, 29, 841450,5,1.08, 12 in same order into newdata to predict the price. Didn't get the Price, just got these above mentioned values only. Am I missing anything here.